# paragraph within a div at very bottom

Tags: html, css, alignment, paragraph

How can I position a paragraph within a div to the very bottom?

I am trying a position-relative (on div), position-absolute (on p) combo but it doesn't work. I want the "Read more" text to be at the very bottom of the div because there are several of these divs next to each other and they very in text length.

HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
 <h3><a href="project2.html">Joia</a></h3>
  <p>Concept design for an eCommerce solution for a local art store (exercise).</p>
  <p class="read-more"><a href="project2.html">Read More</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .card-body {
        position: relative;
    }

    .read-more {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: BTW: you can inspect it here: www.stephankardos.com

It's the cards that you find under the expandable / underlined section.

Comment: consider reading *all* the answers of the duplicate and you will find better way than absolute

Comment: @TemaniAfif no need to close the thread. My question differs since I dont have a fixed height.

Comment: where in the duplicate it's refering to fixed height? all the answers works whataver the height of the container

Comment: @TemaniAfif My initial CSS did not have height! I wanted the div to grow depending on paragraph length. The last paragraph of each card, should be on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do this *without* positioning:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.read-more {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h3><a href="project2.html">Joia</a></h3>
  <p>Concept design for an eCommerce solution for a local art store (exercise).</p>
  <p class="read-more"><a href="project2.html">Read More</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can show here. Refer this link https://codepen.io/joxmar/pen/NqqMEg

Comment: Hmmm ... it doesn't work on my site :/

Comment: Flexbox doesn't work, because I can't specify a certain height. The paragraphs between header and last sticky-to-bottom paragraph vary.

Comment: Flexbox probably will work as I assume you have multiple cards all the same height. The height in the demo is just for demo purposes.

Comment: Actually, the full structure is 
<article>
  <img>
  <div>
    <p></p>
    <p><a><a/></p>
 </div>
</article>

The img has 50vh. The div doesnt have a size

Comment: But your articles do so all you have to do is extend the flex solution upwards so that your card-body elements are all the same height.